# java - change array

Tags: java, arrays, applet

OK let's say I have this array:

```
public int[][] loadBoard(int map) {

    if (map == 1) {  return new int[][] { 
{2,2,24,24,24,24,24,1,3,0,0,0,1 },  {
2,2,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,0,0,0,1 },  {
1,1,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,3,3,3,1 },  {
1,1,24,24,23,24,24,1,1,1,1,3,1 },  {
1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1 },  {
6,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,1 },  {
6,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,7,7,7,3,1 },  {
6,72,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,7,7,1,1 },  {
3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1 } };  } }
return board;
```

and I can call it doing this:

```
board = loadBoard(1);
```

But... let's say I want to change the number 72 on map 1 array (bottom-left in the array) to the number... 21. Can you do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
board[7][1] = 21;
```

**Explanation:**  When dealing with an array `a[]`, `a[n]` references the (n+1)th element (keeping in mind the first element is `a[0]`.

A multidimensional array is just an array of arrays.  So if you have a 2D array `b[][]`, then `b[n]` references the (n+1)th *array*.

Your value 72 is in the 8th array (index 7), at the 2nd position (index 1).  Therefore `board[7][1]` references that value, and `board[7][1] = 21` assigns it the value 21.

**Aside**:  Sometimes (usually, even) you don't know when you write the code which indexes you want to work with, (say you want to do it generically for all maps).  This code will find *all* occurrences of `72` and replace them with `21`:

```
int numToReplace = 72;
int replacement = 21;
//loop through each nested array
for ( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) { 
   //loop through each element of the nested array 
   for ( int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++ ) { 
      if ( board[i][j] == numToReplace ) {
         board[i][j] = replacement;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation as to how you got your answer for his sake?

Comment: Thanks for that - I just didn't want your correct answer to get hijacked :)

Comment: @Dan: Everybody's "stupid" when it comes to learning something new.  If there's something basic that you don't know, it's legitimate to assume that you also won't understand why it works if I just post the code.  @SB wasn't implying anything with that request.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Funny thing is I already knew that code. I just forgot it. So it's not learning something new but retaining that information. :P

Comment: @Dan - never meant to imply anything like that at all.  Sorry if I did.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an array like int[][], you use two indexes to identify a single value in the two-dimensional array.

When initialized like

```
int[][] myarray   = {
 { a,b,c,d,... },  // 0
 { a,b,c,d,... },  // 1
 { a,b,c,d,....}   // 2
};
```

The first index selects one of the nested arrays. (0, 1 or 2) in the example. The second index then selects an item from the nested array, a,b,c,d... above.

The indexes always start from 0: myarray[0][0] gives the value stored in array 0, position a. myarray[1][3] gives the value 'd' from nested array 1.

In your example, the number 72 was in the 8th array, second position, counting using natural numbers (from 1). But since indexes start from 0, this becomes index [7][1]. Which is the answer.

```
board[7][1] = 72;
```